# Match .jpg file extension in URL using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to find out if a given URL contains an image with .jpg extension.  If it does, then I have to remove this extension.

Example:
Request URL: http://www.example.com/image.jpg

The result should look like: http://www.example.com/image

Can anyone help me with a regex for matcing .jpg and removing it?

Comment: post some input and expected outout

Comment: you can use `\.jpg` and replace with ``.

Comment: Just use `pathinfo` (http://ideone.com/Kz4QaJ)

Answer (score 5):

```
(.*)\.jpg
```

Try this.replace with `$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/77

Answer (score 2):

**Regex:**

```
\.jpg(?=\s|$)
```

Th above lookahead asserts that what follows the substring `.jpg` must be a space or end of the line.

**Replacement string:**

```
Empty string
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yM6gQ0/1)

Comment: `http://some.jpg.com/`, `http://foo.com/generate.jpg.php`, `http://foo.com?some=foo.jpg` etc.